# Is time the property of an object?

Tags: time, relativity

I don't know if the title makes much sense, but hopefully it will become clear with the text.

Temperature is not a property of a point in the three dimensions, but actually of the object occupying that point. Similarly, is time the property of the point in three dimensions or of the object occupying it?

If time is the property of an object, take the example of the twin's prardox in relativity. The twins have different ages, but it seems to me that they share the same time after they both stop at earth.

EDIT:In case we say that time is an independent dimension, (just like z on a graph is independent of x and y), then the question is how does age relate to time? If time is not the property of an object, then age seems to be one. But then what is age? Can it be compared to distance/displacement?

Answer (score 8):

Age in relativity is called ["proper time"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time).

In relativity, we have a four-dimensional "[spacetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime)" which is independent of the objects in it (although in general relativity it is coupled to the objects in it).  Spacetime is composed of [events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28relativity%29).  Anything that happens in the history of the universe happens at some event or other.

Time is then one of four labels for an event (the other three being spatial labels, such as x,y,and z).  The labeling can be done in different ways depending on your [reference frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference), so different observers may have different times for the same thing.  However, time is not dependent on the object at an event.  It depends on what event you're at and what reference frame you're in.

An object moving  through spacetime will exist at many different events over the course of its history.  The string of all the events an object visits is called its worldline.  The age of an object is a function of the "length" of its [world line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line).  This age is called proper time; it is a natural parameter for the world line.  Inside a given reference frame, the square of the differential of the proper time, $\textrm{d}\tau^2$ is some quadratic function of the differentials of coordinates, meaning 
$$\textrm{d}\tau^2 = g_{00}\textrm{d}t^2 + g_{01}\textrm{d}t\textrm{d}x + \ldots + g_{33}\textrm{d}z^2$$
Once we know all the coordinates of the worldline and all the coefficients $g_{\mu\nu}$, we can find the proper time $\tau$ by integrating over the entire worldline.  (It is not always possible to cover all of spacetime with one coordinate system, so we may need to do more than one integration.)  The coefficients $g_{\mu\nu}$ depend on the reference frame used as well as the underlying geometry of spacetime.  Once we know them, we can find the proper time, and therefore the age, of an object.  So proper time is a property of an object's history.  Time, as a coordinate, is not.

Answer (score -1):

yes. time is property of matter. there are 3 fundamental dimensions which in mathematical graphs are usually called x axis, y axis and z axis. time is measure of motion of matter through these 3 fundamental dimensions. for example a rotation of earth is called day and a conplete revolution of earth around the sun is called a year. time is a human made concept and to answer your question "is time property of object?" i would elborate that when a repetetive change in state (position) of matter is observed by humans they call it time. there is no 4th fundamental dimension. time is an illusion the same way life is an illusion. if there were no objects i.e, if the universe was just the vaccum then there would be no time. answer: yes, time is property of object. without matter time would not exist. time still does not exist; everything is just matter interacting with each other in 3 dimensions.